# Rails render as json, include nested attribute and sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to render an object as json, including nested attributes and sort them by created_at attribute.

I'm doing this using the code:

```
format.json  { render :json => @customer, :include => :calls}
```

How can I sort calls by created_at attribute?

Comment: I guess you can define the default sort while defining the relationship. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Comment: @tjameson They are calling the render(:json) method, I think it is safe to refer to it as rendering JSON in this context.

Comment: Sorry to be a grammar nazi, but "render" does not deal exclusively with graphics.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you think how Rails works, calls is just a method that relates to the Call model.  There are a few ways you can do this.  One is to set the order option on the association.  One is to change the default scope of the Call model globally, another creates a new method in the Customer model that returns the calls (useful if you wish to do anything with the calls before encoding.)

Method 1:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :calls, :order => "created_at DESC"
end
```

**UPDATE**

For rails 4 and above use:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :calls, -> { order('created_at DESC') }
end
```

Method 2 :

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Method 3:

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recent, order("created_at DESC")
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  def recent_calls
    calls.recent
  end
end
```

Then you can use:

```
format.json  { render :json => @customer, :methods => :recent_calls}
```

Comment: How to put multiple `methods`
I tried `:method => :abc, :xyz`
it's not working

Comment: @iamkdev `:method => [:abc, :xyz]`

Comment: in Rails 5.0, the `:order => 'created_at DESC'` doesn't work any more, should use `-> { order('created_at DESC') }`

Comment: @Gazer I have Rails 4 and `:order => 'created_at DESC` does not work, and got `ArgumentError - Unknown key: :order`

Comment: @tkhuynh Please see the comment above yours.

Comment: @Gazer, I'm confused, Spark was talking about Rails 5

Comment: This is amazing.