# Rails: Prevent JSON hash from being re-ordered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have the following method in my `ContactsController`:

```
def index
    @contacts = {}
    company = current_employer.company
    groups = company.groups.pluck(:name)
    contacts = company.contacts.order(last_name: :asc)

    contacts.each do |contact|
        @contacts[contact.id] = contact.as_json
        @contacts[contact.id][:groups] = {}
        contact_groups = contact.groups.pluck(:name)

        groups.each do |name|
            @contacts[contact.id][:groups][name] = contact_groups.include?(name)
        end
    end
    binding.pry

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: { contacts: @contacts } }
    end
end
```

This generates a `@contacts` hash where the keys are the contact IDs, but the hash is ordered by the contact's last name. If I put in a binding.pry I can see that the hash is in the right order that my client expects, however once it's rendered, the hash is reordered by contact IDs.

Here is a sample of what `@contacts` looks like:

```
{
    contacts: {
        24: {
            id: 24,
            first_name: "Foo",
            last_name: "Bar",
            email: "foo@foo.co",
            groups: {
                Test: true,
                Random: false,
                Example: false
            }
        },
        31: {
            id: 31,
            first_name: "Jackie",
            last_name: "Chan",
            email: "chan@example.com",
            groups: {
                Test: false,
                Random: true,
                Example: false
            }
        },
        28: {
            id: 28,
            first_name: "Jason",
            last_name: "Rebourne",
            email: "jason.rebourne@example.com",
            groups: {
                Test: false,
                Random: false,
                Example: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Normally this is desirable behavior, however in this case I'd like to disable it so as to avoid additional iteration through the response on the client side. How can I prevent the hash from being reordered?

Note: I don't have a custom serializer for my `Contact` or `Group` classes.

**Edit**

This is not a duplicate question. I want to return a custom JSON structure, not a standard serialized structure, which is what the linked "duplicate" question is about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails render as json, include nested attribute and sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972406/rails-render-as-json-include-nested-attribute-and-sort)

Comment: I want to preserve the structure of the hash (contact ids as keys). That answer helps me if I want to return an array of contacts ordered by last_name, but not a hash.

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory answer to this question? I am encountering the same problem.

Comment: I didn't. I ended up just reworking my client side to consume a more standard data structure (e.g. an array of hashes) rather than a hash of hashes.