# Order nested association in as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class User
  has_many :posts
end
```

I want to render a json hash with the [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) method.

How would I order the posts in the code below by their `updated_at` attribute without setting a default order on the association?

```
user.as_json(include: {posts: {include: :comments})
```

This will not be used as a request response and I'd like to avoid setting a default sorting on the association.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails render as json, include nested attribute and sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972406/rails-render-as-json-include-nested-attribute-and-sort)

Comment: @Slava.K Thanks for your effort, but where do you see `as_json` in the question you found?

Comment: All the technics listed in that answer works the same way for `as_json` as well. Just try it out.

Comment: @Slava.K Sounds fantastic! Could you please give an example how that could look like, cause I've tried without success?

Comment: You can create a method and call with as_json like `user.as_json(methods: : permalink)` in this method set your logic in a way, that will give you records with `updated_at`  order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of scope you may use custom method:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts

  def updated_posts
    posts.order("posts.updated_at").as_json(include: :comments)
  end
end

user.as_json(methods: :updated_posts)
```

This will produce something like this:

```
{
  # user attributes
  "updated_posts => [
    # posts with comments
  ]
}
```

If you wish that posts to be strictly under the `posts` key, you may do the following:

```
json = user.as_json(methods: :updated_posts)
json[:posts] = json.delete(:updated_posts)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a working solution! But it's a pity that there doesn't seem to be any inherit way to do this. With the handy helper methods like `:only`, `:ecxept` it's a really nice and fast way to sculpt small json objects.